# Euclidean vector normalization that preserves the inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a set of vectors $\{e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_m\}$ in a Euclidean space $\mathbb E^n$ such that for all distinct $i$ and $j$, the inner product satisfies the following property: $\langle e_i, e_j\rangle\in[-1; 1]$.

Does there always exist a set of unit vectors $\{e'_1, e'_2, \ldots, e'_m\}$ in $\mathbb E^n$ such that for all distinct $i$ and $j$, the inner product satisfies the following property: $\langle e_i, e_j\rangle = \langle e'_i, e'_j\rangle$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not always. Consider in $\Bbb{R}^n$ the three vectors:
\begin{align*}
e_1 &= (1, 0, 0) \\
e_2 &= (-1, 0, 1) \\
e_3 &= (-1, 0, -1).
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
e_1 \cdot e_2 &= -1 \\
e_1 \cdot e_3 &= -1 \\
e_2 \cdot e_3 &= 0.
\end{align*}
If there were unit vectors $e'_1, e'_2, e'_3$ with the desired properties, then
$$e'_1 \cdot e'_2 = e'_1 \cdot e'_3 = -1,$$
which would imply that $e'_2 = e'_3 = -e'_1$. We would therefore be forced to have $e'_2 \cdot e'_3 = 1 \neq 0$.

Comment: (Also, I assumed $e_i \cdot e_j = e'_i \cdot e'_j$ is only required for all **distinct** $i$ and $j$.)

Comment: What are the arguments for your claim that  $e'_1 \cdot e'_2 = e'_1 \cdot e'_3 = -1$ implies $e'_2=e'_3=-e'_1$?

Comment: @JensSchwaiger For any unit Euclidean vector $u$, there exists a unique unit Euclidean vector $v$ such that $\langle u, v\rangle = -1$. The vector $v$ equals $-u$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you, this is a compelling counterexample. I updated the original post to include “distinct”.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger Since the $e'_i$s are all norm $1$, we obtain Cauchy Schwarz equality: $(-e'_1) \cdot e'_2 = \|-e'_1\| \|e'_2\|$. This occurs if and only if $-e'_1$ is a positive multiple of $e'_2$. Since both are norm $1$, this positive multiple must be $1$. The same argument works for $-e'_1$ and $e'_3$.